# Call to undefined method EE_Pagination::create()

Tags: pagination

I have this code in my module

```
$this->EE->load->library('pagination');
$pagination = $this->EE->pagination->create(__CLASS__);
...
```

The problem is that I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Pagination::create() in ...
```

I am using EE 2.5.5

Is there some changes that make this code not work? Is there a new way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create() method in pagination library was only added in EE 2.6

In one of my modules, I use this code:

```
if ($this->EE->config->item('app_version') >= 260)
{
$pagination = $this->EE->pagination->create(__CLASS__);
}
else
{
$pagination = new Pagination_object(__CLASS__);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no create method, there's create_links or render.

Two methods I use:

```
//###   Prep the Pagination   ###
$this->EE->load->library('pagination');
$pagination = new Pagination_object(__CLASS__);
//###   Set any settings   ###
$pagination->dynamic_sql = TRUE;
$pagination->basepath = $this->EE->functions->create_url($this->EE->uri->uri_string);
$pagination->per_page  = ( !is_numeric($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('limit')) )  ? $defaultLimit : $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('limit');
$pagination->build($total, $primarySQL);
$tagdata = $pagination->render($tagdata);
```

...or:

```
    $this->EE->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $total;
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['num_links'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['first_link'] = '1';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<div class="pag-first">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<strong>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '';
    $config['last_link'] = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<div class="pag-last">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->EE->pagination->initialize($config);

    return $this->EE->pagination->create_links();
```

References:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html